# How would you say "something that affects user experience" in 1-2 words?

Tags: single-word-requests

I work in game development and I'm trying to create a concise label for my co-workers that will be used to mark all features and bugfixes that will make their way into the next release and affect the end user experience in a noticeable way.

So far I only came up with 'user-affecting' but I think there's a better way to call it. Suggestions?

Comment: "User-facing", "frontend"?

Comment: So these changes will have a ***User impact***

Comment: *user-visible* behavior, *user-level*

Comment: call them *priority 1*, then call the other categories *priority 2*, etc. then you can make as many categories as you like, and someone will coin a name for them eventually.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for internal works, the standard is just to label it "UX/UI" and be done with it. Short and memorable.

Comment: It does not necessarily have anything to do with UI. Besides, UI/UX is generally one of the main areas in game development. It's like labelling something 'Code' or 'Art'. Thing is, it could be a code task or an art task or a bugfix in our task tracker. I just need a concise label that people will use to denote that users will notice the effects of a given task once it makes its way into a release.

Comment: How about user-friendly?

Comment: Yep, **UX** is the catch-all term that is getting more and more popular, especially in web designing and programming circles where this thing truly matters.

Answer (score 0):

Changes that make your product better will in all likelihood increase your user approval rating.  So the addition of features and bug fixes that 'affect the end user experience in a noticeable way' might usefully be labelled ***kudos enhancing*** (*kudos* - glory, fame, renown (OED)), because they will, in the final analysis, add to the kudos of your enterprise.